# Image not loading in React app using Webpack

Tags: reactjs, webpack

I am trying to load a local image in a simple React application with Webpack. I load the image as:

```
const DogImage = require('../../public/dog.jpg');
const Image = () => {
...
<img src={DogImage} width="100px"/>
}
```

My webpack config includes the following:

```
output: {
      filename: 'widget.js',
      path: path.resolve(bundleOutputDir),
      publicPath: '/public/'
    },
    devServer: {
      contentBase: bundleOutputDir,
      publicPath: '/public/'
    },
...
{
          test: /\.(png|jpe?g|gif)$/i,
          use: [
            {
              loader: 'file-loader',
            },
          ],
        },
```

When I build the app, I get the image file named 8ce03579ff1756938e787945c032a0a3.jpg in my dist folder and when I console.log the image I get:

[image]

It shows up on the screen with the HTML missing file icon. The image is definitely in the correct path because I can't build if the path doesn't match the image.

Please let me know if you have any ideas or if I can provide more info! Thanks

Comment: What is the HTTP response code for the image request?

Comment: There is the following error message: Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)

Comment: Does the request match the full url path to the file? i.e., https://yourdomain.com/public/8ce03579ff1756938e787945c032a0a3.jpg

Comment: No, the path is in /public/dog.jpg but when built the file goes into /dist/8ce03579ff1756938e787945c032a0a3.jpg

Comment: I've changed it to dist but still have the same result. Ie. now the request is reading from /dist/8ce03579ff1756938e787945c032a0a3.jpg and that file exits.